# cannot use admin.modeladmin subclass

Tags: django

I've started Django for 2 days and I get stuck in this section. I want to change the admin section but my class couldn't inherit from (admin.modeladmin). when i want to use list_display,nothing load, and python give me this error:

<class 'django.contrib.auth.admin.GroupAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'title', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'GroupAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'auth.Group'.
<class 'django.contrib.auth.admin.GroupAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'view', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'GroupAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'auth.Group'.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import articles

class articlesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=("title","view")
admin.site.register(articles)
```

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`admin.site.register` requires two parameters: the model object and the admin class.

```
admin.site.register(articles, articlesAdmin)
```

(As an aside, it's conventional to name all classes, including models, in PascalCase and singular, so `Article` instead of `articles` and `ArticleAdmin` instead of `articlesAdmin`.)

The error seems to hint that you've maybe somehow edited `django.contrib.auth.GroupAdmin` instead. If that's the case, I'd recommend uninstalling the Django library and reinstalling the same version, so you're sure to have unmodified code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import articles

class articlesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("title","view",)
admin.site.register(articles,articlesAdmin)
```